# Need help understanding Zend_Form decorator rendering

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-decorators

I have

```
$title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('title', array('size'=>'20'));
$title->setLabel('Title')
               ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
                ->setDecoratorsarray(
        'ViewHelper',
        array(array('dataz'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class'  => 'input')),
         array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
         array('row'=>'HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div','class'=>'element')),
    );
```

I need help understanding how to set parameters.

- Why do we first point ViewHelper not the end?
- Why 2 times html tag between the label?

If I change their position, it doesn't render correctly.

Why only in last option would you want to warp elements (label and input) in the div with class "element"? If I only define `HtmlTag` once it warps only input elements together, not  both label and input.

How do I wrap both elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('title', array('size'=>'20'));
$title->setLabel('Title')
               ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
                ->setDecorators(array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array(array('dataz'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class'  => 'input')),
         array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
         array('row'=>'HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div','class'=>'element')),
    ));
```

Sorry it was some mistake in code.

Comment: Edit your question instead of making corrections in an answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Nags! Is this an answer that solved your problem, or a correction to a typo you made in your question?